# Twitter Bootstrap: keep sidebar width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new with Twitter bootstrap, how do I achieve layout like this website's fluid lay out using Twitter bootstrap?  http://www.smashingmagazine.com/

What I need it the sidebar being the same length through out the certain media type.  I tried

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row-fluid">

      <div class="span9">...</div>

      <div class="span3">  
        <div class="sidebar">...</div>
      </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

What do I do so that `span3` length is always kept at 300px

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure about your query..

You may try appending this to your code and see if it works for you..

```
<style>
  .row-fluid .span3 .sidebar {
    width: 300px;
  } 
</style>
```